# Android taking camera return empty intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am developing android app and my app have button to take camera. Previously i had fallen into a state where return data in **onActivityResult** after taking picture being **null**. This is camera expected behaviour whereby if we put `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in intent , it would return `null`. For that reason , I did null checking code and it went fine .

Now again after a few days and i tested . I still fallen into same issue again. But this time `data` is not `null`. `data` has empty intent such as `intent` and `data.getData()` become `null`.I fixed this by checking `data.getData() == null` and it works again.  I don't why it is like that. Just curious about what was going on. For that reason i have to re-upload to production again. :-(

```
//camera intent
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra("requestCode", Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Intent chooseImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
chooseImageIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
chooseImageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
chooseImageIntent.putExtra("requestCode", Constants.REQUEST_CHOOSE_FROM);

//app can use camera
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    //add output file path which camera will save image to
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Helpers.getOutputMediaFileUri());
    //create choose
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(chooseImageIntent, "Select From");
    //add take camera intent as first intent
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,new Intent[]{takePictureIntent});
    //open up dialog
    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(chooser, Constants.REQUEST_CHOOSE_FROM);
} else {
    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY);
}
```

**EDITED**

I know I how to fix the problem. What i don't understand is return `data` must be `null` if i put in **EXTRA_OUTPUT**. Mostly importantly the code I implemented few weeks back , i am quite sure that `data` return `null` and suddenly it is non `null` value again.

Comment: Don't use `data.getData()`, instead use `data.getExtras().get("data");`, See if issue raises again.

Comment: the reason i don't use `data.getExtras()` is cuz if i pass the extra_output in intent , `data` become `null`. That's fact if i am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually the camera intent doesnot return the data in intent because after getting image it kill the activity.

so try this


 void opencameraForPicture(int requestCode, Uri fileUri) {
        checkPermissionForMarshMello(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.CAMERA_INTERNAL_CLASS);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        /* start activity for result pass intent as argument and request code */
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

    }

    /**
     * This method set the path for the captured image from camera for adding
     * the new  picture in the list
     */
    private Uri getOutputMediaFile() {

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "."
                + Constants.CONTAINER);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        Uri uri = null;
        if (mediaFile != null) {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

        }
        return uri;
    }

in @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

String imagePath = fileUri.getPath();

//you can decode this path as bitmap

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rohit but i don't see any difference with my code . Can you point out why `intent` return data is suddenly become non null value ?